# Something is wrong - min/max fan values are equal(6500)

Tags: macos

I had an issue with my MacbookAir 2014 last month and I had to erase my hard drive and restore from Time machine backup. Since then, fan of my mac is always making noise. To test what happend, I installed Mac Fan Controller app and now this is what I see.

Min/ Max value of fan is same. 
[image]

If I want to update it, I get this error message:

> Something is wrong - min/max fan values are equal(6500)

[image: Something is wrong - min/max fan values are equal]

I tried to reset SMC after reading some blog over internet. My Reset procedure was

1. Removed the Macs Fan Control app
2. Shutdown my mac and keep the power connector on.
3. Press Shift+Control+Option *(left of keyboard)* at once and press power button. Keep like that for 10 sec.
4. Then release all the buttons at once and power on the mac.

But nothing happen.. Min/Max values are always same.. I am not sure if my sms reset worked or not and how to take the min value to default.

Mac details for reference:

[image]

TIA
Ariful

Comment: When you say your "fan is making noise," what type of noise is it making?  If it is failing the very last thing you want to do is manipulate it so it doesn't make noise.  You will want to get it fixed  Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) by holding D while booting from a powered off state. Let's see what errors you are getting, if any

Comment: I Run the Apple Diagnostics already.. The report says everything is ok.. **noice** might be a poor choice of word by me.. main problem is, even if the mac is idle, the fan is rotating in max RPM.. its that noice of max rpm.

Comment: The fan is there for a reason - it needs to cool the CPU.  If the fan spins up, it means the CPU temp sensor says it's too hot.  Either it is too hot and it needs to cool or you have a malfunctioning sensor.  But keep in mind that having the fan spin up even if the computer is "idle" is normal behavior.